# Why use Varnish instead of Symfony proxy?

Tags: symfony, caching, proxy, varnish

I am always asking this question: why use Varnish instead of Symfony proxy? Is there anything more than "Varnish is a dedicated proxy, Symfony is also managing other features, so Varnish is better"? Or "just" because Varnish is written in C? I didn't find any link where I can have a technical point about why Varnish proxy is better than Symfony proxy.

Do you have any information to share with me about this?

Answer (score 5):

It outperforms Symfony cache by a large margin and also has many features that Symfony's HTTP cache does not have.

https://www.symfony.fi/entry/symfony-benchmarks-symfony-proxy-vs-varnish